# MongoDB + java. Как достать данные и работать с ними!

Tags: java, mongodb

Как вытащить значение ключа и использовать ее?  Для примера, вот документ,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
в нем есть ключ idAll и значение ключа "1", как его вытащить и использовать далее, пытался сделать следующее,
сначала в строку

```
  Document founded = collection.find(Filters.eq("id", 0)).first();
                    if (founded != null) {
                        String perN = founded.getString("idAll");
                        System.out.println(perN);
}
```

Выдает ошибку
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
at org.bson.Document.getString(Document.java:288)
at MoneyCar.main(MoneyCar.java:49)

Пробовал и в число:

```
                    int foo = Integer.parseInt(founded.getString("idAll"));
                    System.out.println(foo);
```

все равно не выходит!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге пробовал сначала так:

```
       Document founded = collection.find(Filters.eq("id", 1)).first();
        if (founded != null) {
            System.out.println(founded.getString("money") + " " + founded.get("Description"));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(founded.getString("money"));
            String result = builder.toString();
            int foo = Integer.parseInt(result);
            System.out.println(foo*2);
        } else {
            System.out.println("По запросу ничего не найдено");
        }
```

Получалось через раз (странно, да?). В итоге решил вопрос следующим образом:

```
            Document found = collection.find(Filters.eq("id", 0)).first();
            if (found != null) {
                foo = found.getInteger("idAll")
...
```

Где foo уже переменная класса int, а значит можно производить арифметические действия.